# Working with an array of both int & str in Go

Tags: go, tuples

I am trying to use an array in Go but I cannot find anything that works with both integers and strings in the same array. I am looking for some documentation that would help me with this problem.

I have it working in Python and I am trying to translate it into Go.
Most of the information I found online is showing either arrays of integers or arrays of strings but not both combined.

The integer & string will be passed into another function, depending on the value of the integer determines which string will be concatenated to the string value of the array.

This is an example from Python:

```
# This is the set arrays
List = [[1, "Pie"], [10, "Fish"], [5, "apples"]]

#This is the code of the function that each array will be passed into
 if list[0] == 1:
        return "There is one " + list[1] + "."
    else:
        return "There are " + str(list[0]) + " " + list[1] + "."
```

Final Print Output:

```
There is one Pie.
There are 10 Fish.
There are 5 apples.
```

Comment: The Tour of Go might be a helpful resource.

Comment: if ordering does nor matter use a `map[int]string`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend going about this like so

```
type Foo struct {
  Number int
  Text string
}

  // ...
  array := []Foo{{Number: 1, Text: "pie"}, {Number: 10, Text: "fish"}, {Number: 5, Text: "apples"}}
  if array[0].Number == 1 {
    fmt.Println(array[0].Text)
  }
  // ...
```

Answer (score 3):

If you *really* want to do this with arrays only:

```
List:=[][]interface{}{ {1,"Pie"}, {10,"Fish"}, {5, "apples"} }
```

Then, you can do type assertions:

```
intValue:=List[0][0].(int)
strValue:=List[0][1].(string)
```

However, a better way would be to define a struct containing an int and string member and use an array of that.

Answer (score 0):

Using the solution above I was able  to get the basics of what I needed.

```
// The function determines if it's one of or more than 1
// Giving the correct English sentence

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

type Foo struct {
    Number int
    Text   string
}

func main() {
    // change the value of fish between 1 and 10 to test the function works as expected
    // List could be pulled in from somewhere else then ran through this function
    array := []Foo{{Number: 1, Text: "pie"}, {Number: 10, Text: "fish"}, {Number: 5, Text: "apples"}}
    for i := 0; i <= 2; i++ {
        n := strconv.Itoa(array[i].Number)
        g := (array[i].Text)
        if array[i].Number == 1 {
            fmt.Println("There is " + n + " " + g + ".")
        } else {
            fmt.Println("There are " + n + " " + g + ".")
        }
    }
}
```